# JavaFX - Handle Exceptions in one place

Tags: javafx

I am working on JavaFX application and I want to know if there is a way to handle exceptions in one place.

I am doing inserts into database. And when an insert fails, I get an SQLException.

So, is it possible to handle all SQLExceptions (for all inserts) in one place?

I'm aware of:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...);
```

But this is probably not the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad practice to call any code that executes your SQL query (or any other business logic that may take long to execute) directly in the JavaFX application Thread. (I've observed that under Windows JavaFX applications crash without even printing a stacktrace when an uncaught exeption is thrown in the application thread.)

I would suggest to call your SQL-related code using an  [`javafx.concurrent.Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).
Using the [`setOnFailed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnFailed(javafx.event.EventHandler)) method you can have code invoked whenever an Execption is thrown. There you can look for the type of exception and call any method that handles your `SQLException`.

```
    Task<SOME_TYPE> mySqlTask = new Task<>() {
        @Override
        protected SOME_TYPE call() throws Exception {
            ... // do sql stuff
            return mySqlResult; // or null if not needed
        }
    };

    mySqlTask.setOnFailed(event -> {
        Throwable exception = mySqlTask.getException();
        if (exception instanceof SQLException) {
            // call code that handles the sql exception
        }
    });

    // start the task in a separate thread (or better use an Executor)
    new Thread(mySqlTask).start();
```

By the way, I don't think that using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...);` is the way to go neither.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that.